# AR / VR Toolkit import scene for large models does not work or take ages

Tags: autodesk-forge

I try to import a scene from a Navisworks file. 
Steps to reproduce:

1) Forge Menu > Import Scene

2) Apply credentials

3) Check "Load Metadata","Load Mesh & Materials","Create Collider","Save Asset to disk"

4) > Import

After importing Unity hangs up. 
I checked the activity controller and noticed that unity writes a huge among of data to disk. Check images below. Is this as expected ?

I already imported a bigger scene from a revit file. It tooks about 10 mins with similar results. But i was able to create a prefab from this file.

The import of the navisworks file tooks over 1,5h and ended without any errors and an incomplete model. (The downloaded asset folder is about 60MB)
Downloading the file at runtime takes about 1,5 mins and works fine.

[Written data after 1 min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g4Wz.png) //
[Written data after 15 min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GQ4K.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AR/VR Toolkit](http://forgetoolkit.com) is internally designed to eventually support streaming content to lower-end devices. As a consequence of that, importing models with large amount of objects (especially Navisworks ones) can take a lot of time and resources to process and import.

If you don't mind processing the Forge content into a Unity-supported file format yourself, try taking a look at https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-extract. It's basically a light-weight version of the AR/VR Toolkit that transforms a Forge model into a [glTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/README.md) file which you can then import to Unity with one of the [plugins](https://github.com/search?q=unity+gltf+import).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just tried it and it works fine even at runtime (y).However, I miss the metadata in the objects. So I wanted to do it with the Forge Importer. I have now loaded the model as FBX from Navisworks directly into Unity.